Homology of Genus 2 Surface, writing an element as linear combination of basis
Let $M_g$ be the orientable surface of genus $g$ (the "$g$-handles Torus"). In class we saw that $H_1(M_2) \cong \Bbb Z ^4$ and, on the internet, I found the following generators

My question is: How can I write the following cycles as linear combination of $A_1,A_2,B_1,B_2$? (The pruple one, and the green one).

Context: I'm thinking $H_1(M_2)$ as the abelianization of $\pi_1(M_2)$, or as closed curves in $M_2$ under the equivalence relation "there is a surface inside $M_2$ whose boundary is this two curves" (this second definition is, probably, not accurate, but close enough).
Anyway, I'm looking for a heuristic argument by drawings. For example, this would be $A_1+A_2$

And this is not the cycle im looking for. I have the "crossing", but I need to cancel out the "going inside the donuts".
Note: Perhapes it's easier for me to think of $\pi_1(M_2)$. This four elements do generate the fundamental group. Writing the pruple and green closed curves as concatenations (modulo homotopy) of $A_1,A_2,B_1,B_2$ would definitely answer my question.

Your pictures are beautiful. But, you should supplement that with some mathematical context, as suggested here. A typical example of context is to explain your own attempts on this problem.

I don't know how much context I can give. I've tried doing some linear combinations of $A_1,B_1,A_2,B_2$ in my mind, and got a headache. The pruple and green cycles are interesting cycles to me, for no particular reason. Knowing how to write those cycles in a basis might be useful in my life, eventually

Well, here's some context you can supply. I see that you have used the tag homology-cohomology. But I also see that your post does not mention homology at all, outside of that tag. Do you know the difference between equality of cycles versus equality of homology classes? Can you explain, in any more detail, based on homology theory, what it means to you to "write [the purple cycle, say] as a linear combination of $A_1$, $A_2$, $B_1$, $B_2$"?

So in your middle drawing, there is very clearly a subsurface that is bounded by $A_1$, $A_2$ and the purple curve which I will denote $P$: if you cut the torus along $A_1 \cup A_2 \cup P$ then you get two components, each of which has $A_1 \cup A_2 \cup P$ as its boundary. This could indicate that $P$ is a linear combination of $A_1$ and $A_2$.
But there is an issue here: the $A_1$ and $A_2$ curves have been assigned an orientation (the arrows), and so they do indeed represent cycles and therefore homology classes; however the purple curve has not by assigned any orientation, so it does not yet represent a homology class. If you assign the purple curve the correct orientation, representing a cycle $P$, then the presence of that surface yields the homology equation $A_1 + A_2 + P = 0$ and so $P = -A_1 - A_2$. The correct orientation to make this happen is the right--to--left orientation on the purple arc as depicted in the second drawing; this can be determined by comparison with the right hand rule on the $A_1$ and $A_2$ curves.
Regarding the green curve which I will denote $G$, it also is very clearly the boundary of a subsurface: if you cut the surface along $G$ then you get two components, and the boundary of each component is $G$. So, no matter what orientation you assign to $G$, you get $G=0$. So yes, $G$ is a linear combination of $A_1,A_2,B_1,B_2$ in homology, namely $G=0 A_1 + 0 A_2 + 0 B_1 + 0 B_2$.

In closing, let me say that this concept of "there is a surface inside $M_2$ whose boundary is the given curves" is not actually a complete description of a homology class. Instead, you have to learn about "a 2-chain whose boundary is the given curves".

Is G a contractible loop? It doesn't seem like it, but I thought homology class = 0 implied contractible loop. I clearly need to sharpen my understanding, your answer was very clear.

Homotopy class = 0 implies contractible loop. Not so for homology class = 0.
